# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, mysql, рекурсия

Выдает ошибку

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Увеличить лимит Recourse пытался и не раз. Не поможет.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, telegram_id):
        user_attr = get_user_attributes_by_id(telegram_id)
        self.id = user_attr[0]
        self.username = user_attr[1]
        self.x_loc = user_attr[8]
        self.y_loc = user_attr[9]
        self.region = Region(user_attr[8], user_attr[9]) #OBJECT
        self.citizenship = State(user_attr[4]) #OBJECT
        self.party = Party(user_attr[11])
        if user_attr[13] == 0:
            self.factory = 0
        else:
            self.factory = Factory(user_attr[13])
        self.exp = user_attr[14]
        self.level = get_user_level_by_experience(self.exp)
        self.money = user_attr[5]
        self.gold = user_attr[6]
        self.oil = user_attr[7]
        self.energy = user_attr[10]
        self.party_voted_status = user_attr[12]
        self.parliament_voted_status = user_attr[15]
        self.is_party_candidate = check_party_candidate_exists(telegram_id)
        self.factories_tuple = get_factory_list_by_owner_id(telegram_id)

class Factory:
    def __init__(self, id):
        attr = get_factory_attributes_by_id(id)
        self.id = id
        self.name = attr[1]
        self.owner = User(attr[2]) #OBJECT
        self.type_code = attr[3]
        self.type = return_item_type_by_int(attr[3])
        self.date_created = attr[4]
        self.region = Region(attr[5], attr[6])
        self.wage_proc = attr[7]
        self.production = attr[8]
        self.workers_list = get_factory_workers_list(id)
        self.workers_count = get_factory_workers_count(id)

class State:
    def __init__(self, state_id):
        attributes = get_state_attributes_by_id(state_id)
        self.id = state_id
        self.name = attributes[0]
        self.head = attributes[1]
        self.money = attributes[2]
        self.gold = attributes[3]
        self.oil = attributes[4]
        self.tax_work = attributes[5]
        self.parliament_mandates = attributes[6]
        self.regions_list = get_regions_belong_by_state_id(state_id)
        self.regions_count = get_regions_belong_count_by_state_id(state_id)
        self.parliament = Parliament(state_id)

class Parliament:
    def __init__(self, state_id):
        self.state = State(state_id)
        self.deputies_list = get_deputies_list_by_state_id(state_id)
        self.deputies_tuple = get_deputies_tuple_by_state_id(state_id)
        self.deputies_count = get_deputies_count_by_state_id(state_id)

class Region:
    def __init__(self, x_loc, y_loc):
        attributes = get_region_attributes_by_id(x_loc, y_loc)
        self.name = attributes[0]
        self.x_loc = x_loc
        self.y_loc = y_loc
        self.belong_to_state = State(attributes[1]) #OBJECT
        self.gold_factor = get_region_resource_level_by_factor(attributes[2])
        self.oil_factor = get_region_resource_level_by_factor(attributes[3])
        self.users_nearby = get_users_nearby(x_loc, y_loc)
        self.users_nearby_count = get_users_nearby_count(x_loc, y_loc)
        self.factories_nearby = get_factories_nearby_list(x_loc, y_loc)
        self.factories_nearby_count = get_factories_nearby_count(x_loc, y_loc)
        self.factories_nearby_tuple = get_factories_nearby(x_loc, y_loc)

class Party:
    def __init__(self, id):
        if id == 0:
            self.id = 0
            self.name = "Беспартийный"
            self.short_name = "-"
            self.head = None
            self.date_created = None
            self.belong_to_state = None
            self.votes_for_parliament_elections = None
            self.elections_status = None
            self.members_list = ""
        else:
            attributes = func.get_party_attributes_by_id(id)
            self.id = id
            self.name = attributes[1]
            self.short_name = attributes[2]
            self.head = User(attributes[3]) #OBJECT
            self.date_created = attributes[4]
            self.belong_to_state = State(attributes[5]) #OBJECT
            self.votes_for_parliament_elections = attributes[6]
            self.elections_status = get_party_elections_status(id)
            self.members_list = get_party_members_list_by_id(id)
            self.members_count = get_party_members_count_by_id(id)

class PartyCandidate:
    def __init__(self, telegram_id):
        attributes = get_party_candidate_attributes_by_id(telegram_id)
        self.id = attributes[0]
        self.user = User(attributes[1]) #OBJECT
        self.party = Party(attributes[2]) #OBJECT
        self.date_nominated = attributes[3]
        self.votes_for = attributes[4]
        self.status = attributes[5]

class Item:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.emoji = return_item_type_by_int(id)
        self.id = id
```

Где-то прочел, что это ввиду бесконечных вызовов функций, но как в таком случае придумать альтернативу?

Comment: У вас объекты циклически бесконечно создают друг друга.

Comment: Спасибо! А есть другой способ реализации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если объект A ссылается на объект B, а B ссылается на A, пусть A при создании объекта B передаёт в конструктор B ссылку на себя. Тогда в конструкторе B не нужно будет создавать нового объекта A.